# A div that does not overflow

Tags: css

I have a div that will hold some text. The width of the div is fixed in pixels. I want to make sure that if the text takes more space than one line in the div, the text does not overflow and does not wrap to a second line.  I just want it to show as much as fits the width of the div on one line. I have been experimenting with

```
{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1em;
    width:160px; 
}
```

and it sometimes works, but I don't have the right height.  What would be the right height? There is probably a better way to do this.  Please let me know. Thanks!

Thanks everyone for your contributions. Here is what worked for me:
for a div:

```
{
    height:1.2em;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

note that both `text-overflow:ellipsis;` and `white-space:nowrap;` need to be there for the ellipsis to show.

And for a span note that spans don't have a width so you need to add:

```
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:160px;
}
```

for spans to work

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow:hidden;
height:1em;
width:160px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
line-height: 1em;
```

Will add an ellipsis to text if it overflows the enclosing div and set the div to only use 1em, the height of the container.

Answer (score 2):

`white-space: no-wrap` will prevent a wrap of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Set the line height for the paragraph, then set the div height to be the same. 
Just note that text is usually taller than 1 em, 1.3 or 1.4 is usually better.

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/PYA3y/

```
#mydiv{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1.4em;
    width:160px; 
}
#mydiv p{line-height:1.4em;}
```

**Edit:**

in the time I wrote my reply, you got 3 other answers!
Scott had a good idea for using the ellipsis, I've updated the JSFiddle to include it (although it doesn't work??)

If I understand correctly, setting white-space will not give you the result you require... you do want the extra text to be hidden, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1em;
    width:160px; 
}
```